# why to use cryptoswift framework when apple already provides keychain for security?

Tags: ios, cryptoswift

I am trying to learn cryptoswift framework for data encryption in iOS, but why to use cryptoswift framework when apple already provides keychain for security?

Comment: Because Cryptoswift does so much more. I use it for hashes, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Apple `Keychain` usage is about saving your data in the app in a most secured way.

It is like saving your data in a **safe**. Well protected. No outsider can touch things inside.

`Keychain` is not mutually exclusive with any `Crypto Methods` - where you can opt to use both.

The most common case is you want to transfer your sensitive data over the internet. You might want to encrypt those data before sent even with presence of `https` connections.

Then you need to encrypt your data in your app and decrypt it in the server side. `Keychain` is the best place to save your `Crypto Keys` to do encryption. In this case, the `Crypto Keys` are also the data that want to be secured.

Take a look on the Apple official doc.

[Keychain Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services)